# How can I change the background image opacity without affecting the background color?

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with a background color and a transparent background image.

HTML

```
<div class="watermark">
    <div class="col-md-12">Something else</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something more..</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something at the end</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background-color:white;
}

.watermark {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.watermark::after {
  content: "";
 background:#C52F11 url(https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png)no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg0xgm9t/23/)

I want to be change the opacity of the image, but leave the background color unaffected. But when I set the opacity, both change.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `rgba` color value and remove the `opacity`. For a white overlay you may use `background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);` while the last value (in this case 0.5) defines your transparency.

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg0xgm9t/27/).

Comment: This is a good point, but is it not the wrong way round? They want to change the opacity of the image, not the color

Comment: This is just what I was after. Thanks Aer0. It's geniuses like you who make the rest of us look bad :-)

Comment: lol thanks for the blandishments, but I wouldn't call me a genius. At least I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: @Urbycoz just a detail,`rgba` works on IE9+, if you still need to support IE8 you'll have to create a 1x1 pixel image with the color and the transparency you want and then use it as: `background:url(yourImageUrl.png) repeat;`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `::before` pseudo-element to handle the background color, so that the `::after` element has the image and opacity change, and the `background-color` can be unaffected. Note that the `background-color` of the actual `.watermark` element needs to be transparent, as the `z-index:-1` will push the pseudo-elements behind the actual one.

```css
.watermark {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.watermark::before, .watermark::after {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 
}

.watermark::before {
  background:#C52F11;
}

.watermark::after {
 background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="watermark">
    <div class="col-md-12">Something else</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something more..</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Something at the end</div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg0xgm9t/30/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS for body , whatever you want

```
body{
    background-color:white;
}
```

main div(.watermark) with background color, width and height of your choice

```
.watermark {
    width: 538px;
    height: 190px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #C52F11;
}
```

watermark after CSS , image with opacity

```
.watermark::after {
    content: "";
    background: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png') no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 538px;
    height: 190px;
}
```

I would recommend to use two divs. Its always a good idea to have two divs in overlapping stuffs with relative and absolute. Moreover, it adds long life to your code structure before you have to change it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick:

1. Insert the image into the webpage anywhere(regardless of the size).
2. Set the desired opacity by `style="opacity:0.7;"`  (for opacity= 0.7).
3. Take a snapshot of that image.
4. Remove that image and insert the snapped image where ever you want.